# App crashes after using findViewByID in android studio app development

Tags: java, android

I am using findviewbyid option in my Java app development. When I build my app, it opens and gets closed automatically. When I don't use findviewbyid, the app run smoothly

[image: Screenshow]

I tried various solutions, but they didn't work.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots/images of the code, post the actual code as code formatted text. Presumably your application crashed with an exception, so also make sure to include that exception (again, as code formatted text, not as an image).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i dont see any exception while building the project

Comment: There would more likely be an exception when you **run** your application.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yh i found .

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Comment: Can you also add your xml layout file?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `findViewById(R.id.emailField)` is returning `TextInputLayout` and not `EditText`. You need to further get `EditText` from `TextInputLayout`.

```
TextInputLayout emailTextInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.emailField);

emailField = emailTextInputLayout.getEditText(); // get your editText view from text input layout
```

Do the same for password field as well.